# WinSCP.exe missing in .NET Core AWS Lambda Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, winscp-net

I have developed a .NET Core 6.0 using WinSCP 6.1.0 NuGet package. Locally, from my own PC, I can access a SFTP server, obtaining connection and being able to PUT files.

When I deploy my app as a AWS Lambda function I get the following error on `Session.Open()`:

> WinSCP.SessionLocalException: The winscp.exe executable was not found at location of the assembly WinSCPnet (/var/task), nor the entry assembly Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport (/var/runtime), nor in an installation path. You may use Session.ExecutablePath property to explicitly set path to winscp.exe.

I am aware that for a Azure Function I can set `ExecutablePath` like this, and it works:

```
[FunctionName(FunctionName)]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%XXXSendSchedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext executionContext)
     using (Session winscpSession = new Session())
     {
          // See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_microsoft_azure_function_sftp
          winscpSession.ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(executionContext.FunctionAppDirectory, "winscp.exe");
```

However, in a Lambda function the `ILambdaContext` does not seem to have anything like Azure's `FunctionAppDirectory`:

```
public void MyFunctionHandler(ILambdaContext context)
```

Where can I find the path where the Lambda function keeps `WinSCP.exe` so that I can set `Session.ExecutablePath`?

Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if Amazon Lambda offers storage where you could store the `winscp.exe`, the way Azure Functions do.

But it probably does not matter, as WinSCP is Windows binary and Amazon Lambda (contrary to Azure Functions) offers only Linux systems:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

So I'm afraid that you cannot use WinSCP in Amazon Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin for your answer, it will save me from banging my head against the wall trying to get WinSCP to work in Lambda. I found also backup for your answer:

> The Lambda execution environment is based on a specific Amazon Linux
> AMI and kernel version. Any native binaries that are used in a Lambda
> deployment package must be compiled in this environment, and only
> 64-bit binaries are supported.
>
> From
> https://itnext.io/running-arbitrary-executables-in-aws-lambda-encrypting-a-pdf-afea47e3c345

I will probably try the NuGet package SSH.NET next, as it seems to be a .NET 6 library, hence (I hope :-)) supported by the Amazon Linux.

Henrik

Comment: I can confirm that SSH.NET do indeed work in my .NET 6 Lambda Function, deployed to AWS.